# How to deserialize the string with nondeterministic keys using gson?

Tags: kotlin, gson, deserialization

I have a JSON string in which the keys are not predictable.
The server returns the values with different keys with each response.
Sample JSON looks like -

```
{
    "ids": {
        "123": "08:10",
        "456": "08:00"
    }
}
```

Here, keys `123` and `345` are not fixed i.e. on the next request, my response would look as below -

```
{
    "ids": {
        "123": "08:10",
        "456": "08:00"
    }
}
```

Now, I want to parse this response into an object using GSON. So, I created the model classes as below -

```
data class SlotsResponse(
    val ids: IDs
)

data class IDs(
    val id: Map<String, String>
)
```

And in the code, I am trying to deserialize it as -

```
val response = Gson().fromJson(strResponse, SlotsResponse::class.java)
```

But, I am unable to get the values for `IDs`. They are null.

Can someone please help me to understand whatever I am trying to achieve is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have represented with your current model contains one extra nested object. So it would represent JSONs that look like this:

```
{
    "ids": {
        "id": {
            "123": "08:10",
            "456": "08:00"
        }
    }
}
```

In your actual JSON, there is no field named `id`, so you only need the root object with the field `ids`, and the dynamic map:

```kotlin
data class SlotsResponse(
    val ids: Map<String, String>
)
```

Comment: It worked!!! I had created the models using some Kotlin plugin and was ignorant about them. Thanks!!!